# Accessing object attributes from name (string) inside a list in python

Tags: python, pandas, attributes

I am running a python script that generates multiple variables after iterating over multiple directories. After the script has run, I want to perform some operations on a few dataframes whose names match a specific pattern:

```
failed_runs_finder = re.compile(r'FAILEDRuns_') # pattern to search
list_dfs = list(filter(failed_runs_finder.findall, dir())) # puts the matching results in a list
```

Which gives me a list as shown below:

```
['FAILEDRuns_0112',
 'FAILEDRuns_0121',
 'FAILEDRuns_0126',
 'FAILEDRuns_0129',
 'FAILEDRuns_0131',
 'FAILEDRuns_0134',
 'FAILEDRuns_0135',
 'FAILEDRuns_0137',
 'FAILEDRuns_0142',
 'FAILEDRuns_0153',
 'FAILEDRuns_0165',
 'FAILEDRuns_0171',
 'FAILEDRuns_0175']
```

If I now try to access the number of rows and columns from each of the elements in `list_dfs` with the `shape()` method with the following loop:

```
for i in list(filter(failed_runs_finder.findall, dir())):
    print(getattr(i, 'shape'))
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

This is because the elements in `list_dfs` are, as the error suggests, **strings**, and not the dataframes themselves.

My question is then how can I access the objects themselves by their names inside a list?

Comment: If you want to use the `shape` method, you'll first need to load each file into memory as a dataframe

Comment: they are all already loaded into memory after I run the script

Comment: If you have already loaded all files as dataframes earlier in the script, you could create a dict() where the key is the filename and the value is the df.  in which case you could run a loop such as `for i in list_of_failed_runs: print(df_dict[i].shape)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
for i in list(filter(failed_runs_finder.findall, dir())):
    print(locals()[i].shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got right what you want to do, but you could use a dict to map the string with the dataframe, something like:

```
{'FAILEDRuns_0112': FAILEDRuns_0112}
```

Comment: that helps, though I am now trying to figure out how can I build the dictionary iteratively

Comment: @BCArg How are you currently loading the dfs?  Iterating over a directory/filepath and running pd.read_csv() (or whichever filetype)?

Comment: @cvonsteg: All the dataframes of interest and other objects are created after I run the python script, that's why they appear when I call `dir()`.